# Why is merge-based SCM better than a lock-based system?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, locking

Until now, our development team have used Lock based SCM(Source Control Management) system.
Recently, we have been faced with the necessity of replacing the system with  new, better one.

As a new system, I suggested to use Git.
except a few member of us including me, they've never heard about Git.
so I gave some explanations about it.

the problem is that they think the merging system rather then locking system is 
not for safe to keep integrity of source code.

even though I explained about the Git's system as well as many well-known projects that
have already been using the Git system and awesome reputations of it,
they never felt relieved at the Git.

How can I make them feel relieved about it? 
and How can I explain that merging is not the problem?

Comment: If the seven years of continuous development history by thousands of developers all working simultaneuosly, recorded in every linux repo, isn't enough to demonstrate reliability it's hard to know what would do it.  But nothing stops you using git yourself: make a repo of your svn or whatever worktree, commit the updates as you fetch them, work in a clone, do your own merging, and then push to your double-agent repo and checkin the results to the lock-based repo.  You get all the benefits for your own work, others might start noticing.

Comment: Lock-based systems require more care than merge-based systems. If someone leaves something locked and leaves for a day off nobody else can touch that file without applying some pretty ugly tricks. With a merge-based system this problem does not exist. And merging is not something that should be difficult for a software developer.

Answer (score 0):

Per se merge based system aren't better than lock based system. It all depends on your project. If you have non-mergable files a lock-based system is probably better.

However if I understand your question right, you want to know how to convience your coworkers.

You could argue that linux is a good example, that the linux development would never been possible with a lock based system. However, linux has a huge development base, your team probably hasn't. So it's really not an argument. All the benefits from scalability and multi user does not apply if it isn't a problem for you.

However your coworkers are worried about code integrity. And that's why you should change system. A lock based approach is file centric. (of course there's middle solutions to this problem like svn, but let's say you use something like cvs och vss). However one single files is rarely distributed by its own.

That is, a change in one file will effect other files because they communicate with each other. Using a lock based approach you'll never be sure how your change will affect an other collegues change. If you update file A to rev 2 and test it with file B rev 1 and then your collegue update file B to rev 2, how would you know that it will work? Why would your collegue even think that it can be a problem? He only touched file B, why would he test file A?

With git you take a system based approach to the problem. Each change is a change to the whole repositry and you can always have a version that is guaranteed to work. The point is, looking only on a file you screw the code integrity anyway.